# Selected checkbox items move to another list and add input field inside li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <ul class="collection list-group" style=" text-align:center;" id="list1" data-ref="mixitup-container">
                  <li><a href="#" class="collection-item light-blue active">List 1 <input title="toggle all" type="checkbox" class="all pull-right"></a></li>
                  <li class="item green" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">Second item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                  <li class="item blue" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">More item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                 <li class="item pink" data-ref="mixitup-target"> <a href="#" class="collection-item">Another <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                 <li class="item green" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">Second item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                  <li class="item blue" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">More item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                 <li class="item green" data-ref="mixitup-target"> <a href="#" class="collection-item">Another <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                 <li class="item pink" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">Second item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                  <li class="item green" data-ref="mixitup-target"><a href="#" class="collection-item">More item <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                 <li class="item blue" data-ref="mixitup-target"> <a href="#" class="collection-item">Another <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
               </ul>
  <button title="Send to list 2" class="btn light-blue center-block add"> <i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
                <button title="Send to list 1" style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn light-blue center-block remove"> <i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
  <ul class="collection" style="text-align:center;" id="list2">
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item light-blue active">Selected <span class="all right">Qty</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Alpha  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-left"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Charlie <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Bravo  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Alpha  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Charlie <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Bravo  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Alpha  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Charlie <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="collection-item">Bravo  <input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right"><input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"></a></li>
                   </ul>
```

i want JavaScript code for this list...selected items from list 1 will append to list 2 with input tag is added same like list 2. and if i select list 1 top checkbox all check boxes need to selected.this all i done only problem is i am not able to appending input tag in the list 2 from list 1

and my JavaScript code is.

```
 $('.add').click(function(){
    $('.all').prop("checked",false);
    var items = $("#list1 input:checked:not('.all')");
    var n = items.length;
    if (n > 0) {
      items.each(function(idx,item){
        var choice = $(item);
        var inp = $('<input id="12464" type="number" class="validate qty right">');
        var choices = $(choice.parent());
        choice.prop("checked",false);
        choices.appendTo("#list2");
      });
    }
    else {
        alert("Choose an item from list 1");
    }
});

$('.remove').click(function(){
    $('.all').prop("checked",false);
    var items = $("#list2 input:checked:not('.all')");
    items.each(function(idx,item){
      var choice = $(item);
      choice.prop("checked",false);
      choice.parent().appendTo("#list1");
    });
});

/* toggle all checkboxes in group */
$('.all').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.parents('.collection').find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",true);
    }
    else {
        $this.parents('.collection').find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",false);
        $this.prop("checked",false);
    }
});

$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

/* toggle checkbox when list group item is clicked */
$('.collection a').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();

    var $this = $(this).find("[type=checkbox]");
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.prop("checked",false);
    }
    else {
        $this.prop("checked",true);
    }

    if ($this.hasClass("all")) {
        $this.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

waiting for answer thanks.

Comment: Please provide snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s8aj7eyu/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s8aj7eyu/   please check this link